# Difference between writing `function Name { ...; }`, `Name () { ...; }` and `function Name () { ...; }` in bash

Tags: bash, function, shell, command-line

You can write a bash functions several ways:

```
function JoinStrings {
    ...;
}
```

Or

```
function JoinStrings () {
    ...;
}
```

Or

```
JoinStrings () {
    ...;
}
```

Is there any difference between these functions? Why are there 3 different ways to write a function in bash? (Are there more ways to write function?)

Comment: No difference. The second form (i.e., both `function` and `()`) is very distasteful though. As for why, it's just historical (or so I believe), nothing more. `func () {}` is POSIX, hence portable; the `function` reserved word is bashism. Personally I would write `function` to explicitly break POSIX-compatibility to prevent idiots from sourcing from incompatible shells, e.g. dash (but many would still slip through).

Comment: Are there more ways? No. RTFM: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`function name {}` is the same as `function name() {}`. The only difference between `function name` and `name()` I can think of is that `name()` may be alias-expanded if `name` is an alias. For example:

```
[STEP 100] # echo $BASH_VERSION
4.3.30(1)-release
[STEP 101] # cat func.sh
shopt -s expand_aliases

alias foo=bar

# this will define a function named `foo'
function foo()
{
    echo $FUNCNAME
}

# this will define a function named `bar'
foo()
{
    echo $FUNCNAME
}

unalias foo
foo
bar
[STEP 102] # bash func.sh
foo
bar
[STEP 103] #
```

By the way in `ksh`, `function name {}` is very different from `name() {}`. According to the `ksh` manual:

> For historical reasons, there are two ways  to  define  functions,  the
>   `name()` syntax  and the `function name` syntax, ...
>
> Functions  defined  by the `function name` syntax and called by `name` execute
>   in the same process as the caller and share all files and  present
>   working  directory  with  the  caller.   Traps caught by the caller are
>   reset to their default action inside the function.   A  trap  condition
>   that  is  not  caught or ignored by the function causes the function to
>   terminate and the condition to be passed on to the caller.  A  trap  on
>   EXIT set inside a function is executed in the environment of the caller
>   after the function completes.  Ordinarily, variables are shared between
>   the  calling  program  and  the function.  However, the typeset special
>   built-in command used within a function defines local  variables  whose
>   scope  includes  the current function.  They can be passed to functions
>   that they call in the variable assignment list that precedes  the  call
>   or  as  arguments  passed  as name references.  Errors within functions
>   return control to the caller.
>
> Functions defined with the `name()` syntax and functions defined with the
>   `function name` syntax that are invoked with the `.`  special built-in are
>   executed in the caller's environment and share all variables and  traps
>   with  the  caller.   Errors  within these function executions cause the
>   script that contains them to abort.